# Uncaught ReferenceError in script

Tags: javascript

This is probably straightforward, but I'm not great with JavaScript, so struggling a bit here. I have the following code:

```
//Internet Explorer
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    //Set IE as true
    ie = true;
    //Create a user agent var
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    //Write a new regEx to find the version number
    var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[.0-9]{0,})");
    //If the regEx through the userAgent is not null
    if (re.exec(ua) != null) {
        //Set the IE version
        ieVersion = parseInt(RegExp.$1);
    }
}
else if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
    ie = true;
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null) {
        ieVersion = parseInt( RegExp.$1 );
    }
}
else {
    ie = false;
    ieVersion = null;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(ie == true && ieVersion > 7){
        jQuery("<br />").insertAfter(".entry-title wbr");
    }
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ieVersion is not defined

I'm struggling to see why it isn't defined. Could anybody shed some light?

Comment: define `ieVersion` befor if block, like `var ieVersion = null;` also change your condition to `if(ie == true && ieVersion  && ieVersion > 7)`

Comment: try to declare ieVersion as global variable on top after the <script> tag with var ieVersion

Comment: If the user agent doesn't match the regexp, you don't set `ieVersion`. You should set a default value or add an `else` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your script you have a big if/else if/else block which **might** set `ieVersion`.

Each of the three parts has an assignment for that variable in it, but some of them have it inside a further `if`.

This means that you can, for example, match `if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')` and then fail to match `if (re.exec(ua) != null)` and so never reach an `ieVersion =` statement.

The simplest way to work around this would be to set a default value:

```
ieVersion = null;
```

at the very top of your script.

You *should* also explicitly declare it (`var ieVersion = null`) as this has been considered best practise for a very long time, and JavaScript strict mode requires it.

Comment: I had assumed setting it in the else statement would declare it as that would always be the case if the first two cases weren't applicable, but obviously not!

Answer (score 0):

Either declare `var ieVersion = null;` before the initial method, or use `window.ieVersion`, i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/gys38u4q/